# rails: routing to a html file in the root directory

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails noob here.

I've been fumbling through the process of integrating a wrapbootstrap one page parallax theme (https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ashley-one-page-parallax-WB0R11207 ) into my rails 4 app.

After unsuccessfully attempting to move all JS and CSS to the appropriate assets folders, etc, I contacted the template creator support, and they said that to properly implement, I just needed to place all files in the root directory of my app.

I did this, and the page renders properly when I execute the html file from finder, but I don't know how to route to (set up my root within routes.rb) a html file (index page) that's located in my root directory.  How do you route to a location thats outside of app/views/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't route to a view, you route an action that has associated views with it. just create a custom action in your controller and associate the view with it. if you need further help let me know. we can chat on Skype as well.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  do you mind chatting briefly at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: @dmt2989 just like we discussed you will need to bring all the associated CSS and JS to rails asset pipeline too if you require it to render properly. let me know once you get it working and if you think the answer is worth accepting.

Comment: The issue was that I had brought over all CSS and JSS files that were included with the template, but the folder also contained CSS and JS that was not required, and caused conflicts when being loaded in the asset pipeline.  Once I pruned out all files that weren't required, all worked as expected.  Thx for the help.